Interpretation of Godel's incompleteness theorem
Godel's incompleteness theorem states "Any consistent formal system F within which a certain amount of elementary arithmetic can be carried out is incomplete; i.e. there are statements of the language of F which can neither be proved nor disproved in F." (Wikipedia)
Thus, it seems natural to question whether that "in F" is necessary and to what extent. So, I wonder (let F be a consistent formal system):

Is it known whether there always exists a formal system G such that G contains F and any true statement in F is provable in G?


Moreover, since Godel's Incompleteness also shows F cannot prove its own consistency, does there exist a G that can?


Finally, are there always infinitely many non-equivalent statements that are unprovable F? G?

I'm not familiar with formal logic on the level to comprehend the precise meaning of each term necessary to formalize Godel's Incompleteness Theorem, so these proofs are beyond my comprehension fully, therefore I am only asking if these are known theorems or are easily proven.

"Moreover, since Godel's Incompleteness also shows F cannot prove its own consistency, does there exist a G that can?" A G that proves its own consistency, or a G that proves F's consistency?

"Is it known whether there always exists a formal system G such that G contains F and any true statement in F is provable in G?" What do you mean by "a true statement in $F$" and "$G$ contains $F$"? (I would guess you mean the language of F has some interpretation in which truth values can be assigned, and the language of G can interpret the language of F in some well-behaved way.) Also, I assume you mean for $G$ to also be correct in the sense that it doesn't prove any false statements (pending an understanding of what you mean by true/false), or at least consistent?

And just so I make sure I ask a question about every single subquestion: "Finally, are there always infinitely many non-equivalent statements that are unprovable F? G?" What is $G$?

To your 2nd bullett: see Gentzen's Consistency proof: the result uses a system G ("primitive recursive arithmetic with the additional principle of quantifier-free transfinite induction up to the ordinal $ε_0$" ) to prove the consistency of system F (first-order arithmetic). But G in turn cannot prove G consistency.

this post should be split into 3 posts, one for each question.

First, the most common example of this. There are two famous theories which are comfortable for doing mathematics, Peano Arithmetic (PA), which is a basic arithmetic theory, and Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory with the axiom of Choice (ZFC), a very general theory of sets. Through a coding of natural numbers as sets, statements in PA can be translated to statements in ZFC, and every statement provable in PA can, after the translation, be proved in ZFC. The converse is not true, ZFC being enormously more powerful than PA: there are many statements (even many quite natural ones) not provable in PA which can be proved in ZFC after translating them.
As it turns out, ZFC proves the consistency of PA. This is the classical example of "moving to a stronger theory to prove the consistency of the current theory".
Now, the general case of an arbitrary theory $F$, which I assume (decidably axiomatized, containing Peano arithmetic and) consistent.
By Gödel's first incompleteness theorem, there exists a proposition $P$ which is neither provable nor refutable in $F$. By just taking $F$'s axioms and adding $P$ as an axiom (its negation works too), you get a theory $G$ which is (decidably axiomatized, containing arithmetic and) consistent (because the added axiom $P$ was not refutable in $F$), which proves anything $F$ proves (since it contains all axioms from $F$), and which is strictly more powerful than $F$ (since it proves $P$, which is not provable in $F$).
As for finding $G$ which proves $F$'s consistency, it is slightly more complicated. Gödel's second incompleteness theorem asserts that the consistency of $F$, which I'll denote $\text{Con}(F)$, cannot be proved in $F$. We can try to use exactly the same trick: build $G = F + \text{Con}(F)$. Again, it is decidably axiomatized and contains arithmetic, it proves everything provable in $F$, and it is strictly more powerful because it proves $\text{Con}(F)$, which is not provable in $F$. The trouble is that this theory $G = F + \text{Con}(F)$ might not be consistent, even if $F$ was consistent! There are seemingly paradoxical theories which are consistent, yet prove that they are inconsistent.
The usual example here is $\text{PA} + ¬\text{Con}(\text{PA})$, the theory obtained by adding to PA the axiom that PA is not consistent. This theory proves the inconsistency of PA, therefore it proves its own inconsistency, because it contains PA. Yet, $\text{PA} + ¬\text{Con}(\text{PA})$ is perfectly consistent, because if it were inconsistent, $¬\text{Con}(\text{PA})$ would be refutable in PA, which means $\text{Con}(\text{PA})$ would be provable in PA, and that is not possible, again by Gödel's second incompleteness theorem.
If this seems counter-intuitive, the key is that a consistent theory is not necessarily a true theory. In layman's terms: you can be a liar and yet be perfectly consistent with yourself.
So, if $F$ proves its own inconsistency, then the only way to build an extension $G$ of $F$ which proves $F$'s consistency is to have $G$ be an inconsistent theory (then $G$ proves anything and everything).
To avoid this problem, assume that $F$ is arithmetically true, meaning that any statement translated from arithmetic which is provable in $F$ is true of the natural numbers. (For example, $F$ could be PA or ZFC.) Then, since $F$ is consistent and $\text{Con}(F)$ is an arithmetic statement, $F$ does not refute $\text{Con}(F)$, so $G = F + \text{Con}(F)$ is consistent. What is more, it is arithmetically true, so we can start again with $H = G + \text{Con}(G)$, and so on. In this way, we get statements $\text{Con}(F), \text{Con}(G), \text{Con}(H), …$ which are increasingly strong, answering your last question about infinite sets of non-equivalent statements.
